# Help with calculation of a integral $ \int_c (x^2 + y^2)^{-1/2} \mathrm{e}^{-i k\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x $ (WolframAlpha fails)

Tags: integration, wolfram-alpha

I am trying to solve two definite integrals. WolframAlpha also fails. Could you please help me:

$$ \int_c (x^2 + y^2)^{-1/2} \mathrm{e}^{-i k\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x $$

and
$$
 \int_c ( \frac{\partial }{\partial y} ( (x^2 + y^2)^{-1/2} \mathrm{e}^{-i k\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}))\,\mathrm{d}x $$

So what I need is are 2 integrals along a not closed curve $c$, 
where $ x,y,c,k\in \mathbb{R} $. 
As I wrote in my comment,  it might happen, that $k \in \mathbb{C}$. But this case may be ignored for the beginning.

Here Links to WolframAlpha:
[link1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%28differentiate%20%28exp%28-w%20i%20sqrt%28x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%29%29%20%2F%20sqrt%28x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%29%20%29with%20respect%20to%20x%29%20dy),
[link2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%28exp%28-w%20i%20sqrt%28x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%29%29%20%2F%20sqrt%28x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%29%20%29%20dx)

Comment: Do you need the indefinite integral or the definite integral $\int_{x=0}^\infty$

Comment: What do you mean by $c$? At this typographical place an interval is expected.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $y$ and $k$? Is $k \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: no - $c$ is just a curve. so like from $a$ to $b$ where $a,b$ are scalars. And as for $k$, $y$ and $x$ - no special restrictions - these are scalars. $x,y$ ∈ R. but $k$ might be imaginary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting $x=y\sinh\theta$, the question boils down to finding

$$ \int e^{-iky\sinh\theta} d\theta $$
that is not an elementary integral, but is trivially related with the [Bessel/Hankel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

Comment: thanks - I suppose this is a suggestion for the first integral. Is it suitable to set $x=f(y)$ ? $x$ and $y$ are independent in the initial formulation.

Comment: @KoshaMisa: in your integral (in $dx$) $y$ is just a constant. I am not setting $x=f(y)$, I am setting $x=f(\theta)$ through $x=y\sinh\theta$.

Comment: I see - u'r right. this is definitely one way to solve it. Now, as you've written, the solution for the new integral must be found. I'm not very good in this - could you help me with that?

Comment: It seems that I would get something like an $Ei$ function. Could you show me how the substitution $x=ysinh(t)$ is related to my integral?